# img nested inside div CSS

Tags: css

I want to prevent a nested img inside a div to be resized. This is the CSS I'm using:

```
<div id="profile-gallery-image">
  <img src="..." />
</div

#profile-gallery-image {
border: 2px solid rgba(223,223,223,1);
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;
```

}

and the result I get is this:

[image]

The real image is larger then the 100x100 box. So whatever that's outside it should be hidden.

Comment: Overflow:hidden does exactly what you're asking most of the time, so there must be something else going on.  Can you please post all of your HTML so that we can have a look at tee problem in context?

Comment: Might also add that Im using twitter-bootstrap. Just struck me that maybe the images cant overlap each other and if I create div tags that 100x100 and it fits e.g 5 in a row then the real size of the image collide with one another? Just a thought.

Comment: Even the code you added *should* work.  Can you please post ALL the code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500726/setting-overflow-property-with-twitter-bootstrap-thumbnails Seems like someone else have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the background-size attribute to lock the image size.

Comment: Cant seem to get it right. Tried applying above css properties both to the div tag and img tag. Could you be more specific please?

Answer (score 1):

The container box is not the case here, it seems that the images are resized either via CSS or via some JavaScript.

Try using the following styles:

```
#profile-gallery-image img {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

If this code won't work is means that it's overriden either by JS or by some more specyfic CSS declarations. In this case, inspect those images with Developer Tools or Firebug and check if they still apply. You can also add `!important` to the code (like `width: auto !important;`) but remember to use only if you absolutely have to.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the background-image to display the image inside the div instead of using a separate image tag.

```
<div id="profile-gallery-image" style="background-image:url('images/imagename.jpg');">
</div>

#profile-gallery-image {
border: 2px solid rgba(223,223,223,1);
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:left;
}
```

Comment: If the image is repeating, I don't think it would be good idea to use the ID instead of the class for Divs.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, tried various suggestions that didn't work out.
I wanted a width of 200px but no styling worked.
This is what eventually worked for me. Since my image was in a .png format, I styled the image based on the src file type.

The code below will target ***all** img tags where there is an src attribute ending with .png*

```
img[src$=".png"] {
  width: 200px;
}
```